# How to prompt for user input inside Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to prompt the user for input in `"GroupName"`. Is it even possible?

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "*GroupName*"} | select name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$groupName = Read-Host "Group name"
Get-ADGroup -Filter { name -like $groupName } | select name
```

Edit after comment:

```
Get-AdGroup -Filter { name -like "*$($groupName)*" } | select name
```

Comment: I need the `*groupName*`, so it search for all groups containing the input.

Comment: Better: `-Filter "Name -like '*$groupName*'"`